# Maple find the stationary points

Tags: maple

For the long equation:

$$f = \frac{384x^8-2,304x^7-2,624x^6+41,568x^5-63,693x^4-118,309x^3+418,032x^2-405,405x}{3,072x^2+9,216}$$

I have to find the stationary points in maple between the interval $[-10, 10]$. There should be $3$ stationary points in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To find the stationary points, you need to put $f'(x)=0$ and solve for $x$. Here are the points

$$-3.196276803, -1.460092255, .6491868632 \,.$$

Here are the steps in Maple

> > 1)  g := normal(diff( f, x ));
> >
> > 2)  g1 := fsolve(numer(g),x=-10..10);

As I explained in my comment, the normal command to simplify the expression and numer command to pick up the numerator and equate it to zero, and then fsolve solves it for $x$. Otherwise, you can use the one shot command

> fsolve(diff(f,x), x=-10..10 );

Comment: Is there an easier way to do this besides using normal and numer? A more intuitive way that sets f'(x)=0 like diff(f,x)=0 method?

Comment: @ryantata: I used normal to simplify the expression and then I picked up the numerator and put it equal to zero then solve it for $x$. Exactly as if you solve the problem with your hand. Other wise, you can use the one shot command fsolve(diff(f,x), x=-10..10);.